# How to take alphabet only from string in Freemarker?

Tags: java, regex, preg-replace, freemarker

Anyone expert with Freemarker? 
One of my third-party company uses freemarker, and I don't really know a lot of it.

I just want to take alphabet from string:

Example:

> JAVA2015123100001   -> JAVA
>   PHYTON2015123100002 -> PHYTON

In PHP, I can do it using `preg_replace` like this.

```
$output = preg_replace('#\d.*$#', '', $string);
```

How to do it in Java Freemarker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would ideally do the same thing:

```
<#assign string = string?replace("\d.*", "", "r")>
```

Comment: To enable regex syntax.

Comment: I will try this. I will inform my friend from my company third party to try this.